# Unbound Module GWindow

Tags: emacs, ocaml, freebsd, caml, gtk2

I'm using FREEBSD with Emacs, Tuareg and GTK.
Trying to create my first file but doesn't work.

base.ml:

```
(* file: base.ml *)

let main () =
  let window = GWindow.window () in
  window#show ();
  GMain.Main.main ()

let _ = main ()
```

What I type to compile:

```
ocamlc -I +lablgtk2 -o base lablgtk.cma gtkInit.cmo base.ml
```

The error I get:

```
Error: Unbound module GWindow
```

Can anyone here help me?

This is my makefile:

```
OCAMLMAKEFILE = ../OCamlMakefile

SOURCES = base.ml
RESULT = base
PACKS = lablgtk2
THREADS = yes

include $(OCAMLMAKEFILE)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you insist on OCamlMakefile or answers about another build systems are expected too?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with emacs, you can delete this tag. Moreover, you don't really give the important information here: which version of OCaml is installed, which version of labltgtk2? You provide us with both a command line calling OCaml directly and a Makefile. What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using opam. If it's the case, you can use this compilation command:

```
$ ocamlc -I +../lablgtk2 -o base lablgtk.cma gtkInit.cmo base.ml
```

Comment: I use opam and the compilation fails with the exact error shown by the OP even when I use these switches.

Comment: I added _let locale = GtkMain.Main.init ()_ to fix this.